# Restricting 'Assigned To' Field to only filter users that are within the role they are assigned Territory Management

Tags: apex, validation, user, tasks, territory-management

I have implemented territory model in my salesforce Org. Coming to a particular account I want the related task should not have the user as an option to chose who is owner of the other territory not coming under his/her region

Instead i need users to be only able to make a task for a user within their role/ role hierarchy.

I have tried to use Validation rule in order to get the territory object But it is not visible. Other then that I am still trying to check any option which is feasible under this circumstance to fulfill this requirement.

Comment: What exactly did you try with the hierarchy? Please [edit] your post to share what you have tried so far and where specifically you are stuck. The more specific your question, the better answers you will receive.